# PySpark a way to aggregate/group together different columns data

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame in the following form and I would like to convert it into the shape specified in *data*

```
+----------+--------+-----+
|created_at|   topic|count|
+----------+--------+-----+
|   2020-03|Topic 10| 9711|
|   2020-03| Topic 6| 9699|
|   2020-03| Topic 4| 9439|
|   2020-03| Topic 7| 9169|
|   2020-03| Topic 2| 8951|
|   2020-03| Topic 5| 8665|
|   2020-03| Topic 3| 8553|
+----------+--------+-----+

data = {
    'yyyy-mm': [
          {'Topic 1': [count1, count2, ..]},
          {'Topic 2': [count1, count2, ..]},
          ....
       ]
}
```

I have tried multiple combinations of aggregations and groupBy forms and none seemed to offer a bridge to the final result that I displayed above in data.

Comment: Do you just want to get the data frame into the dictionary format that you've specified?

Comment: Yes, basically that's the goal

Comment: I used basic Python operations to get the other form but I want to see if there is a spark way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I could get using pyspark for most of it but then finishing it off with basic python. I also modified the input a bit to make the grouping stand out:

```
dates = ['2020-03','2020-03','2020-03','2020-03','2020-02','2020-02','2020-02','2020-02','2020-02','2020-02']
topics = ['Topic 1','Topic 2','Topic 1','Topic 2','Topic 1','Topic 2','Topic 3','Topic 1','Topic 2','Topic 3']
counts = [9711,9699,9439,8951,8665,8553,9711,9699,9439]

df = spark.createDataFrame([(d,t,c) for d,t,c in zip(dates,topics,counts)],['created_at','topic','count'])

# +----------+-------+-----+
# |created_at|  topic|count|
# +----------+-------+-----+
# |   2020-03|Topic 1| 9711|
# |   2020-03|Topic 2| 9699|
# |   2020-03|Topic 1| 9439|
# |   2020-03|Topic 2| 8951|
# |   2020-02|Topic 1| 8665|
# |   2020-02|Topic 2| 8553|
# |   2020-02|Topic 3| 9711|
# |   2020-02|Topic 1| 9699|
# |   2020-02|Topic 2| 9439|
# +----------+-------+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType, ArrayType, IntegerType

@udf(returnType=MapType(StringType(),ArrayType(IntegerType())))
def get_dict(topic,count_list):
  return {topic:count_list}

grouped = df.groupBy('created_at','topic').agg(collect_list('count').alias('count_list')).withColumn('dict', get_dict(col('topic'),col('count_list')))
grouped.show()

# +----------+-------+------------+--------------------+
# |created_at|  topic|  count_list|                dict|
# +----------+-------+------------+--------------------+
# |   2020-03|Topic 1|[9711, 9439]|[Topic 1 -> [9711...|
# |   2020-02|Topic 1|[8665, 9699]|[Topic 1 -> [8665...|
# |   2020-02|Topic 2|[8553, 9439]|[Topic 2 -> [8553...|
# |   2020-02|Topic 3|      [9711]| [Topic 3 -> [9711]]|
# |   2020-03|Topic 2|[9699, 8951]|[Topic 2 -> [9699...|
# +----------+-------+------------+--------------------+

values = grouped.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[-1])).collect()

#[('2020-03', {'Topic 1': [9711, 9439]}),
# ('2020-02', {'Topic 1': [8665, 9699]}),
# ('2020-02', {'Topic 2': [8553, 9439]}),
# ('2020-02', {'Topic 3': [9711]}),
# ('2020-03', {'Topic 2': [9699, 8951]})]

data = {}
for d in values:
  if data.get(d[0],None) is None:
    data[d[0]] = []
    
  data[d[0]].append(d[1])

data

# {'2020-03': [{'Topic 1': [9711, 9439]}, 
#              {'Topic 2': [9699, 8951]}],
#  '2020-02': [{'Topic 1': [8665, 9699]}, 
#              {'Topic 2': [8553, 9439]},
#              {'Topic 3': [9711]}]}
```